# Jira api to search all releases in Jira using python

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I used to use JIRA.project_versions(id) to get a list of all releases in Jira in python.
I'm trying to move to using requests.request

I have this to get a count on the number of issues in Jira

```
     response = requests.request(
       "GET",
       url=https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search,
       headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
       params={'jql': 'project=My\ Project', 'startAt': 0, 'maxResults': 0},
       auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user_details.user, user_details.password)
    )
```

And then re-run that with 'startAt' and 'maxResults' set so I can paginate through the issues.

I can't work  out how to do the same to get the list of releases in Jira

Answer (score 0):

Why not getting all versions in a project, and filtering the search query by the same version?

`url = f"{jira_base_url}/rest/api/2/project/{project_key}/versions"`

```
jql_query = f'project = {project_key} AND fixVersion = "{version_name}"'
url=https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search,
```

in a for loop that iterate through each version.